# How can I fix my template loader to check for the root directory?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, satchmo

I have a directory structure like this if it matters (it's the default recommended structure as per satchmo documentation):

```
site
- apps
   | - __init__.py
- config
- projects
   | - site
        | - home
             | - templates
                  | - about.html
                  | - home.html
             | - models.py, views.py, admin.py
        | - __init__.py
        | - local_settings.py
        | - settings.py
        | - urls.py
        | - wsgi.py
   | - __init__.py
- static
   | - css
   | - images (maybe this got autogenerated?)
   | - js
   | - media
- templates
   | base.html
- manage.py
```

My URLs have entries for the about.html and home.html and both of those extend base.html.  However, when I visit the URLs, I get the generic satchmo page with some of my text that I had included from about and home, but it did not extend base.html at all.  Before I installed satchmo, I could confirm that this was working, but now I'm not sure what went wrong. I'm assuming that it's extending some other base.html instead because if I change my extends to master.html instead, it throws a TemplateDoesNotExist exception (which I'm also unsure of how to resolve). I have the following in my settings.py:

```
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
)

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    'templates',
)
```

If I move the templates directory to the site folder within projects, it seems to work, but I don't want it there.  I tried adding '../../templates' to TEMPLATE_DIRS, but that doesn't work either, and even if it did, I'm not sure how that would interact for templates that I declare under some levels of the app folder.  What's the correct way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TEMPLATE_DIRS` entries should be absolute paths. You can do something like this:

```
import os
from os.path import normpath, abspath, dirname, join
BASE_DIR = normpath(abspath(join(dirname(__file__), '..', '..')))
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
)
```

If your master.html is in your templates directory, that error should be fixed, too.

The is 'basis' of the `BASE_DIR` is `dirname(__file__)`, which returns the *directory* containing the current file, `settings.py`. Then, the result is `join`ed with `'..'` twice, that is, we go two directories up, so now we are in the top 'site' directory. We call `abspath` to make sure that it's an absolute path and `normpath` to remove double slashes etc.

Comment: Can you explain what the BASE_DIR assignment actually does? I'm new to Python and I'm not really sure. I also already have this assignment that I copied from somewhere `BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))`. How does this affect things?

Comment: I just put both through the debugger and the result for BASE_DIR was identical.  It also doesn't resolve the issue. Edit: I assume that your assignment is supposed to go up one directory from what I already have, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: The one-dir-up-ness of the `BASE_DIR` should work, I got this exact code in production. But looking at it again, you need to go two dirs up (`site/projects/site/settings.py` and `site/templates/`, so `projects/site` needs to be 'removed' from the dirname of settings.py to get the absolute path of `site` as `BASE_DIR`)

Comment: Ok, so I didn't notice that it was being overridden in `local_settings.py`. It does work now.  Btw, is it better to have such settings as global only since it shouldn't change after pushing to production?  I copied these settings from elsewhere, so I didn't want to break anything initially.

Comment: How are you using `local_settings.py`? Are you doing `from local_settings import *` in `settings.py` or the other way around? Do you have both files under source control?

Comment: The first is how I'm using it.  I haven't set up source control yet.  Trying to get a working prototype first.